# Does anyone know where I can find a Universal Windows Private Network (Client & Server) code Example?

Tags: c#, json, sockets, uwp, private-network

I am brand new to Universal Windows Apps (Win 10). I am trying to port a console application over to UWP that acts as a remote testing and administrative console for a custom Windows Service application. I can not seem to find any solid example code to demonstrate where to place a socket listener in the MainPage.xaml.cs file (or wherever it's supposed to go). I have been successful with porting the MSDN example into a method that serializes a PCL model object with Json and sends it to the server. I just can not seem to handle the listener correctly. I don't think that I am using it in the right place, especially when it comes to the async usage. I am having protocol\port usage errors because it's basically saying that it is already open (I just tossed it in the test method). I would like to deserialize the Json response that is received and use it to populate a List.  Here is an example of what is working for me for sending.

```
    private async void Pulse(string target)
    {

        if (target == null || target == string.Empty)
        {
            greetingOutput.Text = "No Ip specified";
            return;
        }


        else
        {

            try
            {

                Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();
                Windows.Networking.HostName serverHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName(target);
                await socket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, serverPort);
                Stream streamOut = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut);
                HeartBeatPing heartBeatPing = new HeartBeatPing(GetLocalIp(), target);
                string msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(heartBeatPing);
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(msg);
                await writer.FlushAsync();
                Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
                string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();


            }
            catch (Exception xCeption)
            {
                greetingOutput.Text += "\n" + xCeption.ToString();
            }

        }

    }
```

Some of you might notice from the greetingsOutput.text that I have started with the "C# Hello World" example from Microsoft's training site.

I would also like to add that I am not going to be using any HTTP for this because there is going to be some custom encryption and other "things" happening with the Json objects that will require separate ports.

I'm not far enough into my Universal Windows Apps with XAML and C# (Unleashed) books to have even a clue as to what I am doing. I am however well seasoned C# programmer in other platforms such as MVC, Windows Service, Console, and others. I have a solid understand of enterprise class patterns and practices based on my knowledge of "The Gang of Four".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're teetering right on the edge (if not falling into it) of asking for an off-site resource, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may want to reword this to avoid asking for examples/tutorials/web site recommendations/resources (which are all off-topic).

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples duh

Answer (score 1):

(https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DatagramSocket)

Here is a sample. There are `CPP`, `js`, and `cs` code in this sample, I've only tested the `cs` code. Wish this can help you.

Comment: I am able to use this example to create a method that will echo locally. However, when I target my server it seems to time out or lose the thread before the server gets a chance to respond. I've looked into the Network communications in the background tutorial to see if that is the solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt617016.aspx But I am not really sure how to use this and the links for the code examples on github are not responding. Could someone show an example of how such an app would properly "ping" a remote server and wait for a response like a server?